# GCC 7.2 standard library possible constexpr bug in std::distance using the constexpr overload

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, stl, c++17

The function is declared `constexpr` and `std::distance` has a `constexpr` overload. But when I compile with `gcc7.2` I get an error that I don't understand.

It seems to me that there is a bug in `constexpr std::distance`.
The error says it calls `std::__iterator_category(__first));` that is not `constexpr`.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a40a4a2cb44de2ec)

Here is the code and the error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

template<typename It>
constexpr auto max (It first, It last)
{
  auto count = std::distance(first, last);
  if (count == 0)
    throw std::domain_error{"max is undefined on empty range"};
  if (count == 1) return *first;
  auto mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
  return std::max(max(first, mid), max(mid, last));
}

int main()
{
  constexpr std::array<int, 4> vs{1,6,8,3};
  constexpr auto max_of_vs = max(std::cbegin(vs), std::cend(vs));
  assert(max_of_vs == 8);
  std::cout << max_of_vs << std::endl;
  std::array<int, 5> xs{1,9,8,3,6};
  auto max_of_xs = max(std::begin(xs), std::end(xs));
  assert(max_of_xs == 9);
  std::cout << max_of_xs << std::endl;
  //std::array<int, 0> zs{};
  //auto max_of_zs = max(std::begin(zs), std::end(zs)); // throws at runtime
  //assert(max_of_zs == 0);
}
```

error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:23:33:   in constexpr expansion of 'max<const int*>(std::cbegin<std::array<int, 4> >(vs), std::cend<std::array<int, 4> >(vs))'

main.cpp:12:29: error: 'constexpr typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type std::distance(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = const int*; typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type = long int]' called in a constant expression

   auto count = std::distance(first, last);

                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~

In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:66:0,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:39,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/ios:40,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/ostream:38,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/iostream:39,

                 from main.cpp:1:

/usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:138:5: note: 'constexpr typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type std::distance(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = const int*; typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type = long int]' is not usable as a constexpr function because:

     distance(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)

     ^~~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:142:33: error: call to non-constexpr function 'typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::iterator_category std::__iterator_category(const _Iter&) [with _Iter = const int*; typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag]'

         std::__iterator_category(__first));

         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: --> gcc's bugzilla, please.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Ok indeed it is a stdlib bug already in gcc bugzilla. The question was if someone knows about it.